# Write to the registry using silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, registry

I'm working on a LOB application for a client using silverlight..

One of the requirements of this application is to write to the users registry a value which is to be used by another piece of their architecture..

I know this probably raises alarm bells for a few people but is this possible.. and if it cannot be done in silverlight is there another way of doing it (active x perhaps)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a trusted application you can read and write to the registry, writing to the registry is limited to the HKEY Current user.

This awesome post from Justin Angels, will show you a lot of "hidden gems".

http://justinangel.net/CuttingEdgeSilverlight4ComFeatures

Some code:

```
            using (dynamic shell = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("WScript.Shell"))
            {                    

                shell.RegWrite(@"HKCU\Software\Classes\...", ...);
```

Cheers
     Braulio

Comment: Thanks Braulio..  You get the cookie! my boss deicided on a better solution for getting the registry key onto the users machine in the end... not sure if i should be scared :P